# Textbox value to check multiselect parameter based on values JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

Trying to assign ticks to a checkbox and have options selected if the value matches the values in the textbox. This a multi-select parameter.

E.g. if the textbox contains 1,2 when the page refreshes I want to ensure Cheese and Tomatoes is selected. If the textbox contains 1,5,6 then I want to ensure Cheese, Pepperoni and Onions are selected. If the textbox contains 1,2,3,4,5,6 then I want to ensure all checkboxes are selected.

Trying to write some javascript to do this. I tried to use local storage but can't get it working. See code example: https://www.codeply.com/go/rupzwTzBMY

ASPX:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txt1" visible="true" value="" /> 

<div class="container">
    <select id="basic" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Cheese</option>
        <option value="2">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="3">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="4">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="5">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="6">Onions</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Currently when the page refreshes, even if the textbox has values assigned - the checkboxes clear and nothing is selected.
I am trying to ensure when users select items from the multi-parameter when the page refreshes those values are not gone and still remain on the page.

**Javascript functionality that works so far. This puts values in a textbox when you select items from the drop-down. However, when the page refreshes the text box keeps these selected values but the multi-select parameter doesn't**:

```
 $('#basic').multiselect({
    onChange: function () {
        var selectedOptions = $('#basic').val();
        document.getElementById("txt1").value = selectedOptions;

    },


});
```

Comment: Set your value on local storage and when page refresh grab that value from local storage and select value from drop down based on local storage value.

Comment: I have updated my codeply. I tried this but cant get it working. https://www.codeply.com/go/rupzwTzBMY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must reload the select once after populating default values as below

`$('#basic').multiselect('refresh')`

Secondly, try to use `onInitialized` method as described [here](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onInitialized)

Finally, You're trying to assign back values from `TextBox` to `Dropdown` as below, where you're trying to assign the value as such with a comma `1,2` which actually doesn't exist as a value in `dropdown`.

[External Fiddle](https://www.codeply.com/go/aMrTUfV5fD)

```
$('#basic').children("option[value=" +
document.getElementById("txt1").value + "]").prop("selected", true);
```

Split the values as `1` and `2` and then assign and it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    document.getElementById("txt1").value = "1,2,3"

    $('#basic').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            numberDisplayed: 5,
            onInitialized: function(select, container) {
                console.log("Init");
                selectListValues();
            }
        });
        
        $("#basic").multiselect('refresh');
});

function selectListValues()
{
    var txtValue = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    var selectedValues = txtValue.split(",");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++)
    {
        var val = selectedValues[i];
        
        if (val == null || val == "") continue;
        
      $('#basic').children("option[value=" + val + "]").prop("selected", "selected");
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


 <input type="text" runat="server" id="txt1" visible="true" value="" onchange="selectListValues()" /> 

<div class="container">
    <select id="basic" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Cheese</option>
        <option value="2">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="3">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="4">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="5">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="6">Onions</option>
    </select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @roa765, what version of multiselect are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap-Multiselect.0.9.13

Comment: (2) ["1", "6"]0: "1"1: "6"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)

This is in the console - but still checks all boxes on refresh

Comment: @roa765 You must ` $('#basic').multiselect('refresh');` to bulild the select again after selecting values. Check my updated answer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can store input value in local storage, then get inputvalue from local storage then iterate on option set and set selected attribute to true of option if value is present in localstorage.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txt1" visible="true" value="" /> 
<div class="container">
    <select id="basic"  multiple>
        <option value="1">Cheese</option>
        <option value="2">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="3">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="4">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="5">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="6">Onions</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#basic').multiselect({

        onChange: function () {
            var selectedOptions = $('#basic').val();
            console.log(selectedOptions);
            setInputAndLocatStorage();
        }
    });

     function onLoad() {
            if(!localStorage.getItem('selectedItems')) return false;

            var selItems = localStorage.getItem('selectedItems').split(',');
            document.getElementById('txt1').value = selItems.join(',');
             $('#basic').multiselect('select',selItems);
    }

    function setInputAndLocatStorage() {
            var selItems = $('#basic').val();
        var val = selItems == null ? '': selItems.join(',');
        document.getElementById('txt1').value = val;
        localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', val);
    }

     onLoad();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This doesnt work - I selected item 1,6 on my page. Pressed a button which reloads the page and the column checkboxes vanish and the textbox still contains 1,6

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesnt work. The console is showing the correct ones previously selected: <option value="1">Cheese</option> and <option value="6">Onions</option>. The textbox also shows 1,6 but the multiselect parameter has all options ticked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get and populate the value using local storage and split the item.

**Note** 
I had to comment out the local storage so the demo code will work as local storage won't work cross domain. You will need to test this locally.

```js
$(function() {
  //$("#txt1").val(localStorage.getItem('topping'));
  var str = $("#txt1").val().split(",");
  $('#basic').val(str);
  
  $('#basic').on('change', function(){
    var list = $("#txt1").val($(this).val());
    //localStorage.setItem('topping', list);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txt1" visible="true" value="1,2,4" />

<select id="basic" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Cheese</option>
  <option value="2">Tomatoes</option>
  <option value="3">Mozzarella</option>
  <option value="4">Mushrooms</option>
  <option value="5">Pepperoni</option>
  <option value="6">Onions</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesnt work as it loses the current functionality of when you select an item it updates the textbox with the value then when the page reloads it should reselect those values

Comment: @roa765 I think I see what you want now. I havent tested these but I believe it should get and set the value as required.

Comment: Sorry this is still not doing it. I select options 1,5 from multiselect. This value is then stored in the textbox. When the page is refreshed, value 1,5 still remains in the textbox, however the multiselect dropdown has all values selected. Not just 1,5.